# The fetch can not get response from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, fetch-api

I have a question. In the client side, I use fetch API to get response, this is the code

```
window.fetch('/signup', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: formDataStr,
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
.then(function (response) {
  return response.json()
})
.then(function (result) {
  if (result.code === 0) {
    return this.$router.push('/main')
  }
})
  .catch((err) => {
  self.isLoading = false
  console.log(err)
})
```

In the server, it is written in node and express, this is the code:

```
`app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var loginEmail = req.body.email2
  var loginPsd = req.body.secret
  UserDataModel.findOne({ email: loginEmail }, {
    name: 1,
    password: 1,
    email: 1
  }, function (err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    if (!userInfo) {
      res.send({
        code: -1,
        msg: 'user not exist'
      })
      return console.log('user not exist')
    }
    userInfo.comparePassword(loginPsd, function (err, isMatch) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      if (isMatch) {
        req.session.isLogin = true
        req.session.userInfo = {
          userName: userInfo.name,
          userEmail: userInfo.email
        }
        console.log(req.session)
        res.json({
          code: 0,
          msg: 'login succeed！'
        })
        res.end()
      } else {
        res.send({
          code: -2,
          msg: 'wrong password'
        })
      }
    })
  })
})`
```

The console shows that post is successful with status code 200. However, the fetch next then promise can not execute. It seems that there is no response from server.

Answer (score 1):

You use `this` inside a function. It refers to global object.
Try:

```
.then(function (result) {
  console.debug(result); // inspect a result
  if (result.code === 0) {
    return self.$router.push('/main'); // assume you have var self = this above.
  }
  Promise.reject(new Error('Error code: ' + result.code)); // generate an error
})
```

Comment: the self is just this. But I just cannot get respnse from server

Comment: Is there response in Network tab of Developer Tools?

Comment: You don’t show the code which consumes that `response.json()` and it’s not clear what you mean by “the fetch next then promise can not execute”…

`response.json()` returns a Promise, so to get the actual JSON from the response and e.g., output it to the console, you need:

    `response.json().then(function(json) {
      console.log(json);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You client-side code is sending an HTTP POST request to `/signup`, but your server side code is set up to receive POST requests at `/login`. Those URLs need to match, if you want your server to handle those requests from your client.